# At what rate does this sum converge to $\infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ (as a function of $n$)

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, asymptotics, quadrature

Simple question, what is the rate that this sum converges to $\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ (the rate as a function of $n$):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \cfrac{\sin^3(\theta_k^{(n)})\pi(n-1)}{n^2\cos^2((n-\frac{1}{2})\theta_k^{(n)}-\frac{\pi}{4})}\cfrac{1}{1-\cos(\theta_k^{(n)})}\ , $$

where $\theta_k^{(n)}=\pi\cfrac{4(n-k)+3}{4n+2}$.

For context, the first term in the sum is an asymptotic approximation for the weights of gaussian integration, and the second term is an asymptotic approximtion for $1/(1-\xi)$ evaluated at the gaussian integration points (so integrating $\int_{-1}^11/(1-\xi)\text{d}\xi$ using gaussian integration).

Comment: Numerics indicate something like $2\log(n)+\gamma+\log(2)+o(1)$, but I do not have a rigorous proof.

Comment: Incredible simplifications !

Answer (score 1):

After simplifications
$$a_k=\frac{  (n-1)\,\pi}{n^2}\,\tan \left(\frac{  (4 k-1)\pi}{4 (2 n+1)}\right)$$
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \sim 2 \log (n)+(\gamma +\log (2))-\frac{\log (n)}{n}+\gamma\frac{\log(n)+3}{n^2}+\cdots$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 1000 & 15.0790 & 15.0775 \\
 2000 & 16.4684 & 16.4667 \\
 3000 & 17.2804 & 17.2787 \\
 4000 & 17.8564 & 17.8547 \\
 5000 & 18.3030 & 18.3013 \\
 6000 & 18.6679 & 18.6662 \\
 7000 & 18.9764 & 18.9747 \\
 8000 & 19.2436 & 19.2419 \\
 9000 & 19.4793 & 19.4775 \\
 10000 & 19.6901 & 19.6884 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

If we compute the equivalent integral
$$T_n=\frac{(n-1) (2 n+1) }{n^2}\log \left(\cot \left(\frac{3 \pi }{4(2n+1)}\right)\right)$$ and, with $R^2=0.9999999972$, gives
$$S_n \sim T_n+\frac \pi 2$$

Expanded as a series
$$T_n=2 \log (n)+2 \log \left(\frac{8}{3 \pi }\right)-\frac{\log (n)-\log \left(\frac{3 e \pi }{8}\right)}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Notice that $\frac \pi 2+2 \log \left(\frac{8}{3 \pi }\right)=1.24300$ while $\gamma+\log(2)=1.27036$.

**Update**

Using Euler-MacLaurin summation formula
$$\frac {S_n}{n-1}=\frac{2 \log \left(\frac{8 n}{3 \pi
   }\right)+\frac{123265132}{68201595}}{n}+\frac{\log \left(\frac{8 n}{3 \pi}\right)+\frac{129834161}{68201595}}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

Comment: Proof?$\phantom{}$

Comment: @Gary. No proof but numerical heuristics

Comment: Your last correction term is much smaller than the actual error in the table, so it may not be correct.

Comment: @Gary.For sure, it can be

Comment: @Gary. There is an incredible simplification for the summand.

Comment: @Gary. Confirmed by Euler-MacLaurin summation

Comment: What is the asymptotics if you add the Euler-MacLaurin corrections to the expansion of $T_n$?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici , can you show how you did the simplication for the summand (to get $a_k$, your first equation)?

Comment: @JosephRobertJepson. I must confess that, a week later, I do not remember any more. There were intermediate  steps and results. I used basic trigonometric relations based on multiple angle formulae. I shall try to rebuild the process.